# How to select records in the order they were inserted, and then group them by a type

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, grouping

I have a query I can not seem to get to work.
I have a table like this:

ThingID, FK_ThingTypeID, Etc...

And I want to select records in the order they were inserted, but group them by type.  So if the data looks in the table is in the following order:

```
ThingID, FK_ThingTypeID
1        1
2        2
3        1
4        1
```

I want to get select the records like this:

```
ThingID, FK_ThingTypeID
1        1
3        1
4        1
2        2
```

So they are in the order they were added, but grouped by type.

I have tried using ORDER BY and GROUP BY for this but no combination of what I try works, and all the GROUP BY examples I see are working with aggregate functions.  I am not interested in counts or max etc.. I just want to order the records as above.  I have tried just using an ORDER BY ThingID, FK_ThingTypeID, but this just lists them by ID and does not group by the types.  There are a stack more columns in the table and using GROUP BY requires that I add all these, and then it doesn't work anyway.

Can anyone give an example of an approach to achieve the result I am looking for?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for those that responded.
Here was the solution:

```
SELECT
    t.*
FROM
    Thing t
ORDER BY 
    (
        SELECT 
            min(ref.ThingID) 
        FROM Thing ref 
        WHERE
            ref.ThingTypeID = t.ThingTypeID 
    ),
    t.ThingID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems simple so am sure someone will be able to help.
Gotta love Stack Overflow.

I had a go not sure whether this is what you are after?
Apologies if not

```
SELECT ThingID,FK_ThingTypeID
FROM Table
ORDER BY FK_ThingTypeID, ThingID
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I need to get the records in the order they were inserted in the table and then group them by ThinkTypeID.  Unfortunately ordering first by ThingTypeID does not get them in the order they were inserted.

Comment: based on your sample data & required result, this query will gives you the required result. If it is not what you want, you are not giving us the full requirement

Comment: @Squirrel The full requirement is the records will be listed in the order they were inserted, and then grouped by the ThingType.  See the final solution I posted to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

May be this query is helpful for you as per my understanding:

```
select * from table order by rownum, FK_ThingTypeID
```

You can try below query:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
   ORDER BY THINGID) AS RowNum, FK_ThingTypeID  from table
```

Comment: I tried to use this example by I get the error:
The function 'ROW_NUMBER' must have an OVER clause.
When I looked this up all examples are using ROW_NUMBER in the select not the Order By so I am not really sure how to use this?

Comment: I am not getting any error in the execution of above query in oracle database. May be it will not support other database, but if you are using oracle db than this type error should not be come.

Comment: Am using MS SQL Server,(eg; TSQL) I should have specified this sorry.